# How to make a person stop a executing command who started the execution of another command discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a spam command, i want the spam command executer to only be able to stop it. I am confused to how do so. Here's my code (i have tried nothing by by myself yet)
`else if (command === prefix + "spam") {spamText = setInterval(() => {message.channel.send(`${args.slice(0).join(" ")}`)}, 1500);} else if (command === prefix + "stopspam"{ clearInterval(spamText); message.reply("Stopped the spamming. Hope it created some chaos :skull:")}`

Answer (score 0):

you need to extract your interval to be able to stop it

```
function Spam(){
    message.channel.send(${args.slice(0).join(" ")})
}
let myInterval;
if (command === prefix + "spam") {
    myInterval = setInterval(Spam, 1500);   
} 
else if (command === prefix + "stopspam"){ 
    clearInterval(spamText); 
    message.reply("Stopped the spamming. Hope it created some chaos :skull:");
}
```

and be carefull with the use. nobody like spammer

Comment: No no I'm not saying that i don't know how to stop the spam. The code that i provided works perfectly fine. I just want to make the user who started the spam only be able to stop the spam

Comment: ok sorry error from me wait a second I go seek some doc

Comment: if it's as I remember, the command is in a message, and the mesage have a "Author" field (i think it's the id of the author) as said in the doc (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author )